# Simulate keyboard with Jquery on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm trying to experiment some things with js-dos (a plugin of dosbox on browser) and I need a button to simulate a keyboard key (ENTER for example)

I've tried creating an onclick event and inside the function,a Jquery "keypress" event,but nothing seems to work.

I've tried this:

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
        var val=13;
        $("canvas").trigger({
            type:keypress, keyCode:val,which:val,charCode:val
        });
    })
```

and this

```
var e = jQuery.Event('keydown');
    e.which = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
$("canvas").trigger(e);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Add `listener` to the triggered event.

```js
let e = jQuery.Event('keydown');

$('div').on('keydown', function() {
  console.log('calling');
});


$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div').trigger(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```